# HTTP GET request: Send json object as http request parameter from client to server- but not in request url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, get

I hit HTTP GET api to fetch the data from server end.

I have some data(json data) that i want to send to server to make some decision based on that.

Right now, we are doing and duplicating all this on client side since we don't have anyway to pass it to the server.

Any suggestions? We don't want to use POST.

Comment: Please add your code/sample thereof. It is possible to send data in the request body of the get, but probably worth having a read of this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Are you trying to send `json` through a GET?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to send Jason through get, and not in url parameter

Comment: *So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful to do so.* - Please avoid such a big mistake and use the appropriate HTTP method (in your situation POST).